# How to detect a Select change event if changing between two options with the same value?

Tags: javascript, events, dom, dom-events

```
<select>
   <option value="">Select</option>
   <option value="10000">Minimum Coverage</option>
   <option value="25000">Average Coverage</option>
   <option value="">Other</option>
</select>
```

I have to have both the "Select" and "Other" have empty values because the validation rules on the field do not allow for anything other than an empty string or a numeric value.

Bottom line, is I need to be able to detect when the user is on "Select" and clicks "Other". Is it possible?

EDIT: onChange does not seem to fire.

Comment: Can you make a demo showing `onChange` not firing?

Comment: Give one of them a value of `-1` (or another value that would be out of bounds of your selection) and check for that in your `onchange`

Answer (score 17):

The shorter version would be:

```
 var mySelect = document.getElementById('mySelectId');
 mySelect.onchange = (event) => {
     var inputText = event.target.value;
     console.log(inputText);
 }
```

Comment: getElementById('mySelect'); 
Don't add the #

Comment: I removed the # and changed the Id to a different name than the returned object.

Answer (score 12):

You can check the `selectedIndex` property. If you want something to happen each time the item changes, use the `onchange` event binding.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].onchange = function() {
  var index = this.selectedIndex;
  var inputText = this.children[index].innerHTML.trim();
  console.log(inputText);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sabof/LLpHb/)

Answer (score 9):

The `change` event most certainly fires, even if the changed option has the same value:

[jsfiddle.net/kyw2E](http://jsfiddle.net/kyw2E/)

In the `change` event handler, you can examine the `this.selectedIndex` property to determine which `<option>` is selected.  You can then examine the `text` property of the selected option, if that's helpful:

```
coverageSelector.onchange = function (e) {
    var selectedOption = this[this.selectedIndex];
    var selectedText = selectedOption.text;
}
```