# How do I detect a change in a select element in React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-select

I have an HTML form with a `select` dropdown for users to select a color, and I'm trying to detect when a new color has been selected. I've added the `onchange` attribute with a `console.log()` function, but nothing is printed to console when I select a new color.

Here's my `select` element which is contained in the `return` statement for the form:

```
<select id="color-selector"
        name="colors"
        onchange={() => console.log("Color has changed")}>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
</select>
```

I've seen this is possible in vanilla JS from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795933/how-to-detect-a-select-change-event-if-changing-between-two-options-with-the-sam), but is there a way to do this by using the `onchange` attribute in the HTML in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've misspelled `onChange`. All callbacks in Reactjs are written in camel-case. It's in simple HTML that the attribute is `onchange`.

Comment: Thank you! I was following a simple HTML tutorial for `onchange` which makes sense now why it wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

```js
import React, {
  FormEvent,
  FormEventHandler,
  SelectHTMLAttributes,
  useState,
} from "react";

export default function Home() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");
  function colorChange(e) {
    setColor(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <select name="color" id="color" value={color} onChange={colorChange}>
        <option value="">Select option</option>
        <option value="red">Red</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```